# Remove 1 week from date in php

Tags: php, datetime

Been a long while since I posted here, I have done a LOT of coding without having to ask but I am stuck :(

I have a variable which is called "$date", it is always the current date. Now I have logs which have a date set to them, now what I want to do is delete any logs that are older than a week from the current date. Here's how I'm doing it (? means I don't know what to put).

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$one_week_old = $date - ?;

$clearlog = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM logs WHERE logs.date < '$one_week_old'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$one_week_old = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 week"));
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you :D you will get answer for being a second quicker!

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using another variable, you can just query it directly:

`$clearlog = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM logs WHERE logs.date < 
dateadd(week,-1,getdate()));`

Answer (score 1):

`$one_week_old = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-1 week"));`

Comment: While this answers the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need this date information later in PHP, i suggest you to do that directly in the MySql Query. Please consider, that this example will modify just the datepart, not the timepart of the current timestamp. It was't specified exactly if you like to to have whole days deleted or exactly the those data older then 604800 seconds (7 x 24 x 60 x 60 = 604800).

[MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual 12.7 Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM logs WHERE logs.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 week' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
$query="DELETE FROM logs WHERE logs.date < '".$newdate." 00:00:00 '";
$clearlog = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: This answer would be much higher quality with a little bit of explanation. Also, you don't want to use `\`` in code blocks

Comment: While this answers the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer Oriented Object paradigm, we have:

```
$oneWeekAgo = (new DateTime('-1 week'))->format('d/m/Y');
```

Explanation:

- Return a new DateTimeObject
- Set the timestamp from -1 week
- Format to your need.

Comment: Before my edit it was not "Oriented Object paradigm" whatever it means, but a mess